# How to unpivot data from multiple tab into one tab using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I just tried this lo unpivot automatically from 1 sheets to another and it worked perfectly. however, i have to unpivot the others tab into 1 sheets and i have no idea how to unpivot data from multiple sheets into one. do you guys could help me? thank you

```
function unpivotAndMoveDataInRange(sourceSheetName, sourceRangeA1Notation, targetSheetName) {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
  // Get the source sheet and range
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Jan 2024");
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:AK255");
 
  // Get the values from the source range
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
 
  // Prepare data for unpivoting
  var unpivotedData = [];
 
  // Assuming the first column is the header, and the rest are data
  var headers = sourceValues[1];
  for (var row = 2; row < sourceValues.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 10; col < headers.length; col++) {
      var newRow = [sourceValues[row][1], headers[col], sourceValues[row][col]];
      unpivotedData.push(newRow);
    }
  }
 
  // Create a new sheet for the unpivoted data
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contoh");
  if (!targetSheet) {
    targetSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(targetSheetName);
  }
 
  // Clear existing data in the target sheet
  targetSheet.clear();
 
  // Set headers for the target sheet
  targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([["Name", "Date", "Schedule"]]);
 
  // Write the unpivoted data to the target sheet
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, unpivotedData.length, 3).setValues(unpivotedData);
}
```

i tried to add more sheets on the script but it doesnt work at all

Answer (score -1):

```
Unpivoting data from multiple tabs into one tab using Google Apps Script involves iterating through the data in each tab, transforming it, and then consolidating it into a single tab. Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow:

Accessing Spreadsheet Data:
Open the Google Sheet where your data is stored.
Open the script editor by clicking on "Extensions" -> "Apps Script."
In the script editor, write a function to access the data from multiple tabs.

    function getDataFromTabs() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
      var data = [];
    
      // Iterate through each sheet and collect data
      sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
        var range = sheet.getDataRange();
        var values = range.getValues();
    
        // Add data to the array
        data = data.concat(values);
      });
    
      return data;
    }

Transforming Data:
Depending on your specific unpivoting requirements, you may need to reorganize the data.
For example, if you have data in columns and want to unpivot it to rows, you would need to loop through the columns and rows and create a new array.

function unpivotData(data) {
  var unpivotedData = [];
 // Loop through rows
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    // Loop through columns
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      // Add each cell value as a new row
      unpivotedData.push([cell]);
    });
  });

  return unpivotedData;
}

Writing Data to a New Tab:
Create a new sheet to store the unpivoted data.
Write the transformed data to the new sheet.

    function writeToNewTab(unpivotedData) {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet('UnpivotedData');
      var range = newSheet.getRange(1, 1, unpivotedData.length, unpivotedData[0].length);
    
      // Write data to the new sheet
      range.setValues(unpivotedData);
    }

Run the Script:
Run the functions in the correct order to retrieve, transform, and write the data.
You can run the script from the script editor or create a custom menu or trigger to execute it.

    function runUnpivotScript() {
      var data = getDataFromTabs();
      var unpivotedData = unpivotData(data);
      writeToNewTab(unpivotedData);
    }

Customize as Needed:
Adjust the code according to the specific structure and requirements of your data.
Remember to test the script on a copy of your data to ensure it works as expected. This example assumes a basic unpivoting scenario, and you may need to modify the code based on the actual structure and format of your data.
```

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).